# Best place to write which element to filter in "on click" jQuery

Tags: jquery, onclick

In jQuery you can define the element you click on it 2 ways. e.g. take you wanna check on which button was clicked:

define the 'button' ***before* the on("click")** like this:

```
$("#container button").on("click", function(){
    //code
});
```

or define the 'button' ***inside* the on("click")** like this:

```
$("#container").on("click", "button", function(){
    //code
});
```

What would be the best way?

---

Btw, my code to see which button is active:

```
$( ".view_style").on("click", "li", function(){
        $('.view_style li').removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Is this any good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2 ways serve different purposes. Your first example is simply a nested selector. The second example is a delegated event. The difference is that while both work on existing DOM elements, delegated events work on elements that don't exist yet, but will in the future.

Example 1. You bind both event handlers. Both ways will work correctly.

```
<div id="container">
    <button><button>
</div>
```

Example 2.

```
<div id="container">
</div>
```

You bind both event handlers, except the first will fail because there is no button, so the selector fails. However the delegated event is bound on the container. When you click on the container, the handler searches for a button. You click on it now, no button is found, so nothing happens.

Later, the button is added.

```
<div id="container">
    <button><button>
</div>
```

You click on the button, the delegated event handler finds the button inside the container and executes the handler. Remember, you bound the handler before the button even existed, yet it still works. Delegated events are more flexible, and it saves memory when you need to bind lots of handlers.

Answer (score 0):

The first way mentioned is not used `event delegation` concept meanwhile for the second part used `event delegation`, means that both mentioned ways are completely different. Which one is better its really depends on your code. As you might need to understand what is `event delegation` is. This [page](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) can give you understanding for the differentiate of both. If your code was created dynamically such as pulling data from Database using `AJAX` request, or `append/prepend` it using any jquery method, it's best to stick with 2nd way. So to be more clear i will try to produce sample code based on what you have :

Suppose you have this element in the page :

```
<ul class="view_style">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
</ul>

<button>Add New Element</button>
```

And later on, you added another element programmatically using `.append()` by clicking on `Add new element` button, if you click that button, the new `li` element will appended into `ul` pro grammatically like following :

```
$('button').click(function () {
  var
     ul = $('.view_style'),
     li = ul.has('li').length ? ul.children().last().text() : 0;

  ul.append('<li>' + ( parseInt(li) + 1) + '</li>');

});
```

After that you create another click handler for `li` element itself for example when clicking on it, current clicked element will change the background color and the rest element we remove the color only for active element are have the right to have that style. Here the code to accomplish that, add it under code above :

```
// without delegation
$('.view_style li').on('click',function() {
  // remove active class for 
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
  // only added active class for current clicked element
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

And the `.active` class we specify some style on it :

```
.active{
  background-color : yellow;
  color : red;
}
```

Ok we're done for creating. Let's try it out. I will narrow it down one by one. If you click the `li` element of 1 and 2, you can see the background color was changed. And yes, it's working great for element that already existed. What about for element that dynamically created. So, try add new element by click on `Add New Element` button. You can see the new element was added/appended into `ul` element as a number 3,4,...and so forth. Finally if you click on the newly created element, what the expected behavior? The background color did't added to it and of course the above JS code didt work so great. To fix that, we used `event delegation` concept as like your second way code :

```
// with delegation
$('.view_style').on('click','li',function() {
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

So, to be more clear, you can try to play with this [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/r1zvcek3/). Try to remove event delegation code and leave only the without delegation code to test it out.